# Object handling in arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, object, nsmutablearray

I have read several answers to similar problems on here but I still can't get the code working.

I am trying to keep my code blocks in different sections so I can adjust things as I make them more complicated.

The object hierarchy is `PieceProperties` - which I am trying to store as an array in `PieceStartInfo`, which should be accessible by other function with the `PieceStartInfo.h.`

**The PieceProperties.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PieceProperties : NSObject
- (id)initWithDetail:(NSInteger)PeiceID WithValue:(NSInteger)Value WithOwner:(bool)Owner WithShape:(NSInteger)Shape;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger P_ID;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger P_Value;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) bool P_True_Own;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) bool P_Current_Own;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSInteger P_Shape;

@end
```

With its method file

```
#import "PieceProperties.h"
@implementation PieceProperties
@synthesize P_ID, P_Value, P_Current_Own, P_Shape, P_True_Own;
- initWithDetail:(NSInteger)PeiceID WithValue:(NSInteger)Value WithOwner:(bool)Owner WithShape:(NSInteger)Shape{
P_ID = PeiceID;
P_Value = Value;
P_True_Own = Owner;
P_Current_Own = Owner;
P_Shape = Shape;
return self;
}
@end
```

The Holding Class header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PieceProperties.h"
NSMutableArray *PieceData;
@interface PieceStartInfo : NSObject{
}
- (id) initCreateArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) PieceProperties *PieceData;
@end
```

And the important bit of the method

```
#import "PieceStartInfo.h"
#import "PieceProperties.h"
@implementation PieceStartInfo{ 
}
-(id) initCreateArray{
NSMutableArray *PieceData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:60]; 
NSInteger N_Val, N_Shape;
bool N_Own;
for(NSInteger i = 0; i<60;i++){
    if (i == 0){
// a whole bunch of code defining the N_Val for each i
    }       
    N_Own = (i % 2 == 1);        
    PieceProperties *PInterest = [[PieceProperties alloc] initWithDetail:i WithValue:N_Val WithOwner:N_Own WithShape:N_Shape];
    [PieceData addObject:PInterest];
}    
return self;
}
@end
```

And finally the method of calling from the main function, (tring to access the data of the 3rd piece.

```
    PieceStartInfo *DataArray = [[PieceStartInfo alloc] initCreateArray];
    PieceProperties *IndividualData = [[PieceProperties alloc] init];
    IndividualData = [DataArray.PieceData objectAtIndex:2]
    // then a line like 
    NumberofInterest = IndividualData.P_Value to get a property or use a custom function.
```

The Line...

```
IndividualData = [DataArray.PieceData objectAtIndex:2]
```

Gives the Error

```
No visible @interface for 'PieceProperties' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex'
```

My first thought would be to change `PieceProperties` to be derived from `NSMutableArray` instead but I had a go an it doesn't seem to help: (it is targeting IOS 7.0 with Xcode Build 5.02)

Comment: As a side note, Apple recommends that you stick with the naming conventions for instance variables and properties. This might sound pedantic, but when sharing code, others will be able to read your code with much more ease. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems in your code. For your current error, you'd better do as following:

1) change the property type to NSMutalbeArray * and modifier from `assign` to `strong`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pieceDatas;
```

2) change your init to as following style. and you'd better also change the init method in PieceProperties class.

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _pieceDatas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:60];

        NSInteger N_Val, N_Shape;
        bool N_Own;
        for(NSInteger i = 0; i<60;i++){
            if (i == 0){
            // a whole bunch of code defining the N_Val for each i
             }       
              N_Own = (i % 2 == 1);        
             PieceProperties *PInterest = [[PieceProperties alloc] initWithDetail:i WithValue:N_Val WithOwner:N_Own WithShape:N_Shape];
             [_pieceDatas addObject:PInterest];
        }
    }    
    return self.
}
```

Comment: Thank you it did does indeed solve that error, and so now the code compiles I just run into other problems (associated with memory release), I admit my code is fairly bad at the moment with little memory control. I will get there.

Comment: @Bookkeeper i'm glad it's helpful.You can read something about objective c to learn it faster. And also You can accept my answer if you feel it answer your question :).

Answer (score 0):

Well `PieceProperties` certainly has to inherit from `NSArray` in some way or another because `NSObject` which it currently inherits from doesn't implement `objectAtIndex:.` Thats really all I can tell from your code.

Theres a lot of confusing things in this that make it hard to answer. However, don't forget to assign top the actual property within the `initCreateArray` its also not a very good idea to have two same named variables in a header. In all honesty I would suggest implementing `NSDictionary` so you can store groups of data in an array.. It would make it much more readable! Sorry I couldn't help more!

Comment: Which aspects are confusing, if I get that feed back I it might help me clean the code and help prevent errors.  Logically NSDictonary makes sense though apart from searching which I shouldn't need (I will always know which instance I need to reference) I do not see much advantage or is there other factors I am missing there?